# Split string into array of GUID's

Tags: c#

If I have a pipe separated list can I split them automatically into an array of GUID's?

So

"guid1|guid2"

and then `Guid[] values = selectedValue.Split("|".ToCharArray());` would have been nice.

Comment: That splits it into an array of strings. Now you just have to convert the array of strings to an array of GUIDs. Don't be shy; it's just programming.

Comment: @RaymondChen, yes I realise that but thought there might be a more elegant way and LINQ seems to fit the bill nicely.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Almost:

```
Guid[] values = selectedValue.Split('|').Select(s => Guid.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

If any of the Guids isn't valid, this will throw a FormatException though.

If you want to ignore them, you can do what Jeremy suggest in the comments:

```
"9FE027E0-CF95-492F-821C-3F2EC9472657|bla|D94DF6DB-85C1-4312-9702-FB03A731A2B1"
.Split('|')
.Where(g => { Guid temp; return Guid.TryParse(g, out temp); })
.Select(g => Guid.Parse(g))
.ToArray()
```

Maybe this can be optimized further (We're essentially parsing each number twice) or simply ignored as the 97% premature optimizations that don't matter.

Comment: maybe a `.Where(s=>Guid.TryParse(s, out foo))` of some kind could be shoehorned in there.

Comment: You can avoid the double-parse by using `SelectMany`. `s.Split('|')
.SelectMany(s => { Guid g; return Guid.TryParse(s, out g) ? new Guid[] { g } : new Guid[] { }; })
.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid double parsing I would "re-phrase" it as:

```
"9FE027E0-CF95-492F-821C-3F2EC9472657|bla|D94DF6DB-85C1-4312-9702-FB03A731A2B1"
    .Split('|')
    .Select(g => { Guid temp; return Guid.TryParse(g, out temp) ?  temp : Guid.Empty; })
    .Where(g=>g != Guid.Empty)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: this won't work if one of the GUIDs is Empty 9FE027E0-CF95-492F-821C-3F2EC9472657|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000|D94DF6DB-85C1-4312-9702-FB03A731A2B1